# How can I add elements to a vector inside of a vector when both vectors are dynamically allocated?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct, queue

Here is a very brief description of the project im doing:
I currently have it set up as a vector containing a vector of structs. It can be a vector containing a queue of structs if that would make this easier as the elements will be unloaded FIFO.
I just need to sort the main vector in order of vector/queue containing the most structs.

Here is my code:

```
 MetaV.push_back(vector<sData>()); //create vector inside vector

 //load data into structs

 metaV.back().push_back(item); //push struct onto the vector inside the vector

 //loop struct portion until process changes, then loop to top
```

MetaV is declared as:

```
 std::vector<std::vector<sData>>metaV;
```

sData is the struct and is an object? of that struct declared as:

```
 sData item;
```

Later in the code I can access all elements in the struct in metaV, however instead of being (in the instance of the file) 3 vectors with 14 structs throughout them, MetaV just contains 17 items.

So my question is, how do I add the structs into the dynamically made vectors inside of the vector?
Where is my code wrong?
I thought back() added to the last element, but I guess it adds to the back of it, not inside of it?

I tried to put as little code as possible as I know my error is in those two lines. I can provide more if needed.

Thanks

EDIT: here is the snippet of code if this makes it more complete and verifiable.

```
 item.ident = mcode;
    item.desc = mdesc;
    item.cycle = mcyc;
    item.ncycle = newCycle;
    item.tasks = codeDesc;
    item.taskEnd = codeEnd;
    item.procNum = numProcess;

    metaV.push_back(vector<sData>());

    //if new process, store and reset counts
    if (n != numProcess)
    {
        //create new vector in metaV and push onto it
       metaV.push_back(vector<sData>());
       metaV.back().push_back(item);

        if(sched_code == "PS")
        {
            taskTot = io_count;
            io_count = 0; //reset count for next process
        }

        else if(sched_code == "SJF")
        {
            taskTot = io_count + taskNum;
            io_count = 0; 
            taskNum = 0; //reset counts
        }

        else if (sched_code == "FIFO")
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Scheduling Code Error: " << sched_code << endl;
        }

        countz.proNum = n;
        countz.taskNum = taskTot;

        //push onto vector to be sorted
        procSort.push_back(countz);

        n = numProcess;
    }

    else //if n == numProcess
    {

        metaV.back().push_back(item); //push struct into vector, in vector metaV

    }
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be hard to say anything.

Comment: Everything you describe is OK.  So your program is broken.  Write a simple example that just pushes say 2x3 elements into a vector of vectors.  Then if that still doesn't work we can figure out why.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Stupid mistake, but somehow it took me hours to figure out. When I first create the vector, its still inside of a bigger loop. Hence every time the loop runs It creates a new vector and added the struct to that. The simple fix was to create the original vector outside of all loops. Thanks for your help!